# Why are you taking off your shoes?

Tags: grammar

He took his shoes off.

> "Why **are** you taking off your shoes? Not comfortable?"
>
> "Why **did** you take off your shoes? Not comfortable?"

Those shoes have been took off. 
According to context above, we are using "are" or "did"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is asked after he had taken the shoes off (as I believe your context is establishing) then the correct sentence to use would be:

> "Why **did** you take off your shoes? Not comfortable?"

If the question was being asked *while* he was taking off the shoes, you would use **are**.